# DataGridView & Checkbox Column?

Tags: vb.net, winforms, datagridview

Using vb.net and DataGridView in Winforms.

What event should I use to know when the checkbox has changed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you mean how do you know when the DataGridView changes?

A DataGridView is not a checkbox at all.

Add an event handler to handle a CellValueChanged event.

```
Private Sub MySubName(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As DataGridViewCellEventArgs) Handles DataGridView1.CellValueChanged

End Sub
```

(replace MySubName with whatever you want, and DataGridView1 with the name of your DataGridView).

Fill in the body of the Sub to handle the event.

Answer (score 0):

Is

```
DataGridViewCheckBoxCell.EditingCellValueChanged
```

what you want?

Comment: what is DataGridViewCheckBoxCell? Types as such gets an error.

Comment: You have a DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn right?  They have DataGridViewCheckBoxCell as the cell type:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewcheckboxcell.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You need to set up an event handler to do work when a cell's contents have been changed.  Then, based on the arguments passed, you can see if the checkbox was checked or unchecked, and do work accordingly.

```
    Private Sub myDataGrid_CellContentClick(ByVal sender As System.Object, _
    ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellEventArgs) _
    Handles myDataGrid.CellContentClick
         If myDataGrid.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(e.ColumnIndex).Value = "True" Then
             'Checked condition'
         Else
             'Unchecked Condition'
         End If
    End Sub
```

Hope that helps!